# How to assert the result of a form submission

Tags: dalekjs

I have the following test:

```
var start_url = 'http://example.com/';
var account_email = 'olav@example.com';
var account_password = '****';

module.exports = {
  'test login': function (test) {
    'use strict';
    test
      .open(start_url)
      .assert.visible('#login')
      .click('#login')
      .type('#email-field', account_email)
      .type('#password-field', account_password)
      .submit('#login-form')
      .assert.visible('#logout')
      .done();
  }
};
```

The `.assert.visible('#logout')` does not work. I suspect that I need to introduce some kind of `waitFor()` but I have not found an example of how to do this.

-- Olav

Answer (score 0):

You should add a

`test.waitForElement('#logout')`

after your `submit()` & before your `assert.visible('#logout')` calls.

If this does not work, than it is maybe you hit the max timeout of the `waitForElement` function, you can extend the timeout by setting a second parameter like this:

`test.waitForElement('#logout', 10000)`

You can find more information in the [docs](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-waitForElement)

If this still does not work then, please open up an issue [here](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-internal-actions/issues)

As a workaround I would suggest, to use the `test.wait(7500)` method, but this should be the last option if the solution described above does not work. If thats the case, please open up an issue.

Thanks.